# Advanced Custom Fields Lightbox appears to be showing all images attached to the field instead of those attached to the post

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, lightbox

I created a pop-up lightbox gallery in WordPress using Advanced Custom Fields and while all of the base functionality works, for some reason the lightbox appears to be showing all photos attached to the gallery_photos field across multiple posts instead of just the photos attached to the single post.

```
<?php
  $images = get_field('gallery_photos');
  if($images): ?>
  <div class="gallery" id="post-gallery-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php $i=0; foreach( $images as $image ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" target="_blank" rel="lightbox" class="thumbnail">
    <?php if( $i==0 ) : ?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/camera-icon.png" width="30px" height="30px" alt="" border="0"/>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </a>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can see a sample of how this is working at the [following link to the dev site](http://light.squid.studio/). There's a list of products, defined as a custom post type, and each product has an associated lightbox gallery of photos accessible via the camera icon at the end of each row.

However, if you click the icon you'll actually see photos for all products, not just the one you clicked. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you running the above code inside a loop? you can try passing the post ID as described [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

Comment: Make sure that get_field('gallery_photos') returns you only the data you expect. do a var_dump($images)